# Error de conexión a la unidad de persistencia en netbeans 8.2

Tags: jpa

La unidad de persistencia no me esta funcionando de manera correcta en netbeans , al crear un objeto de tipo EntityManager para conectar a la unidad de persistencia no me realiza la conexión y me arroja una excepción.

> [EL Info]: server: 2017-05-26 14:11:52.735--Detected server platform:
>   org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.NoServerPlatform. [EL Info]:
>   server: 2017-05-26 14:11:52.735--ServerSession(352359770)--Detected
>   server platform:
>   org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.NoServerPlatform. [EL Info]:
>   2017-05-26 14:11:52.735--ServerSession(352359770)--EclipseLink,
>   version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258 [EL
>   Severe]: ejb: 2017-05-26
>   14:11:53.853--ServerSession(352359770)--Exception [EclipseLink-7060]
>   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException Exception
>   Description: Cannot acquire data source [java:app/d]. Internal
>   Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for
>   'java:app/d' in
>   SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
>   java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming,
>   java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl}
>   [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Invocation exception:
>   Got null ComponentInvocation ] error:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-7060]
>   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException Exception
>   Description: Cannot acquire data source [java:app/d]. Internal
>   Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for
>   'java:app/d' in
>   SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
>   java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming,
>   java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl}
>   [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Invocation exception:
>   Got null ComponentInvocation ]

```
public class ClienteDao {
    private EntityManager daogenerico;

    public void conectar() {
        daogenerico = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("IntegracionPU")
                .createEntityManager();
    }

    public boolean crearCliente(Cliente c) {
        try {
            conectar();
            daogenerico.getTransaction().begin();
            daogenerico.persist(c);
            daogenerico.getTransaction().commit();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // daogenerico.getTransaction().rollback();
            System.out.println("error: " + e);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  
    java:app/d
    false

Comment: Ahora solo falta el codigo que tienes actualmente

Comment: la clase  donde tengo el metodo conectar

Comment: Y falta tu archivo `persistence.xml`, que es el que te configura la conexión a base de datos.